# pyinstaller with matplotlib windows

Tags: matplotlib, pyinstaller

I use pyinstaller in generate pythion program with matplotlib a exe file
The exe is generated well but when use the exe, there is a error said no module named 'tz'
what does it mean?

I have test the pythinstaller with program with numby and pyqt4 without matplotlib, it works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXS7i.png) well! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find the solution on pyinstaller git hub provided by Cecil Curry.
It is：
This is a known issue. python-dateutil 2.5.0 is currently broken with respect to PyInstaller, unfortunately.

Until python-dateutil issues a new stable release correcting this, consider temporarily downgrading to python-dateutil 2.4.2. Apologies for the mild inconvenience – and thanks for taking the time to report this, nonetheless.

I have tested and it works